# Video to frames extraction in C#

Tags: c#, video, warnings, frames, extract

I am trying to run a small application in C# on visual studio 2010 that extracts frames from a video. My windows OS is 32 bit.

When I tried to build the solution it gave me the following warning:

"There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "MWArray , version =2.12.0.0 , culture=neural , publicKeyToken=e1d84a0da19db86f, processorArchitecture=AMD64 , "x86" . this mismatch may cause runtime failures. please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the configuration manager so as to align the processor architecture between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project."

**Edit**:

right now i tried to change the project configuration to  x86. now the warning is now disappeared.

i tried to start debug the program is gives an error . 
TypeInitializationException was unhandled.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using finalNative;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;

namespace check
{   
   public partial class Form1 : Form   
   {
      finalNative.edit mtb = new finalNative.edit();  // ... >>here is the error message

      static object Val;

   public Form1()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();

      fdlg.Title = "Select File ";

      fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.avi)|*.avi";

      fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;

      fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

      fdlg.ShowDialog();

      if (fdlg.FileName != string.Empty)
      {
         textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName; 
      }
      else
      {
         textBox1.Text = "Please Select .avi file before submit the form ! ";
         Val = textBox1.Text;
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
      {
        if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
        {   
           mtb.frames(textBox1.Text);

           makeframe.Enabled = false;

           label2.Enabled = false;

           MessageBox.Show("Video Converted into Frames!");
        }

     }

     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        mtb.formating(textBox1.Text);

        MessageBox.Show("Frames Color Should be changed and Saved !");

        formating.Enabled = false;

        label3.Enabled = false;
     }

     private void makevideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            mtb.makevideo(textBox1.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Video Creation complete And Saved with Name "+"resultant video.avi");

            makevideo.Enabled = false;

            label4.Enabled = false;
      }

      private void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { 
         this.Close();
      }

      private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It says right there what you should do...

Comment: yes now i tried to change the configuration there is no warning now. but there is an error when i start debugging .

Comment: What is this error you're getting then?

Comment: its exception handlng msg ... TypeInitializaionException was unhandeled.

Comment: The TypeInitializationException means there was an error initializing the type in question.  This can be a problem loading the assembly (for example, a problem reading the file), or it can be an exception in the static constructor.  In this case, the type you should look at is `finalNative.edit`.  You should also check the InnerException property of the TypeInitializationException.  If it is not null, it will shed some light on the underlying cause of the problem.

Comment: yes I got what you are saying. phoog. thank you. i am using matlab assmbly  "finakNative"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do:

> please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project through the configuration manager so as to align the processor
>   architecture between your project and references, or take a dependency
>   on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

Read about the exception [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yes i have resolved that problem by changing the project configuration. now the warning is disappeared.